# Getting Error Cannot set property 'innerText' of null

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a scenario of adding text to html element using id. But I am getting error.
First the html gets dynamically loaded then I am adding `add variable` to the html element using id `detail`

```
geocoder.geocode({
        'location': temp1
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
            if (results[1]) {
                add = results[1].formatted_address;
                var marker0 = createMarker({
                    position: temp1,
                    map: map,
                }, '<h1>Details</h1><p id="detail"></p>');

            } else {
                window.alert('No results found');
            }
        } else {
            window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }

    });
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var add;
    /*
     * marker creater function (acts as a closure for html parameter)
     */
    function createMarker(options, html) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(options);
        if (html) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(html);
                console.log(add);
                document.getElementById('detail').innerText = add;
                infoWindow.open(options.map, this);
            });
        }
        return marker;
    }
```

Html is getting appended but `document.getElementById('detail')` is giving a null value.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(add);`?

Comment: It looks like a problem of order.  First you call createMarker, then you create id="detail".  So you must rearrange the order of things

Comment: The problem is you call `infoWindow.open(options.map, this);` after `document.getElementById('detail')` so the content hasn't been added to the DOM yet, so try to open the window first.

Comment: is the element with id=detail in the current document or an iframe perhaps?

Comment: Just a question ... why would you add (that p element) id="details" dynamically?  That doesn't make sense.  The reason for doing this, is probably at the basis of the problems you're experiencing.  (Maybe you have multiple p elements with details, then you cannot use id anyway, ...)